# Allow formatting of text in django form (Like the text editor on this site)?

Tags: django, forms

With the basic textfield on django, the user can indent, and that's it. I'd like to allow centering of text, bold, italics, lists, etc. I messed with TinyMCE, but unless there's something I'm missing, it outputs html every time. Am I messing up TinyMCE, or should I take a different route?

Comment: But... you *want* HTML, surely? You're making a website, after all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your variable is safe (doesn't contains harmful HTML code) then you can mark it as safe. This will render the text without escaping HTML tags.

```
{{ variable|safe }}
```